# command doesn't send anything, even though it has been called. there's no errors

Tags: discord, discord.py

i'm currently writing a discord bot and working on a tic-tac-toe. i made a few functions to use inside a main one but only sending simple text with "await" appears to be working.
if there's something more happening inside "await ctx.send()" it just doesn't show up. how do i fix that? thanks

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

numbers_board = [[0, 1, 2],
                 [3, 4, 5],
                 [6, 7, 8]]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.command()
async def turn_tic(ctx):
    await ctx.send("\n".join(numbers_board[i] for i in range(3)))

client.run("my_token")
```

Comment: Could you give any other info like debugging attempts or how do you call this command from discord?

Comment: @wikwoj i used a few functions one after another, such as `
await ctx.send(“that worked”)
print(1)
await ctx.send("\n".join(numbers_board[i] for i in range(3)))
print(2)'
and it printed just "1" and sent "that worked" to discord. if i switch these two fuctions, nothing works. it seems like a fuction inside a fuction freezes the whole command

Answer (score 0):

numbers_board[i] for i in range(3) returns a list of lists, so you are trying to join 3 lists. join() takes in a list of strings. So you would either have to do

```
await ctx.send("\n".join(str(numbers_board[i]) for i in range(3)))
```

or

```py
await ctx.send("\n".join(" ".join(numbers_board[i]) for i in range(3)))
```